# Shall I just ignore if safeTransfer failed?

Tags: solidity

I googled and found that we shall use the following code to avoid paying too much to a contract recursively or consumed too much gas fee in one single transaciton.

```
function safeTransfer(address payable _base, uint value) internal {
    (bool success, ) = _base.call.value(value)("");
    require(success, "SafeTransfer");
}
```

In my use case, I am paying to 10 persons in one call.

I am wondering shall I just ignore if **success=false**. Because if the recipient is hostile, there is no reason for me to fail my entire transaction just because of him.

Comment: If you don't mind losing ether for that one hostile recipient, then you can ignore the value of `success`.

Comment: @goodvibration are you saying that even if **success=false** the ether had been sent to the hostile recipient?

Comment: What do you think the `require` statement is for?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, and it's just for signifying that the function has failed (if that is indeed the case, then I would just `return success`, but maybe the author had a different thought on it).

Comment: @sk Where did you get this piece of code? Sometimes it is used as an alternative to send and transfer, but it has none of the advantages you say: it is not cheaper, it doesn't protect against re-entrancy attacks.

Comment: @Ismael I got it from https://consensys.github.io/smart-contract-best-practices/recommendations/ I do disagree on what they said, but my code can't execute with a simple transfer()

Comment: @sk It isn't mentioned anywhere it being cheaper, they explicitly mention it doesn't protect against re-entrancy attacks. They explicitly mention when interacting with an external untrusted contract use withdrawal pattern.

Comment: @Ismael thank. Actually I can't remember where I got this code from. I was having problem with transfer() and someone told me to use this since it is safer. I have my contract handled the reentrance attack. But I would like to ignore a problematic recipient in the list, may I know what is the best approach to do that now? Try / Catch and silent the problematic one?

Comment: @sk Yes, you can ignore the result of `call`. It will imply that if a transfer fail it will not revert other calls. But it doesn't mean it is safer you are just ignoring an error.